# how to replace a char in a specific index with another char on another index

Tags: java, str-replace

The following code prints `eleelde` but I want it to print `elcaalde`.

How can I do it? Is there a function like replace char at `index()`??

I want to assign the character at `i=0` the value of the char at `i=6` and print the word `elcaalde`.

```
public class ReverseExperiments3 {  
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      String s= "alcaalde";
      s=s.replace('a','e'); 
      System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it in the char array:

```
char[] cs = s.toCharArray();
cs[0] = cs[6];  // For example.
s = new String(cs);
```

Comment: in order to achieve the result, it is 7th element and so s[7]. Anyways, you were right giving it as s[6] as he asked for it

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regex replacement here:

```
String s = "alcaalde";
s = s.replaceFirst("(.)(.{6})(.)", "$3$2$1");
```

### Demo

The answer given by @andy is probably the best one for this exact problem.  But if the OP needed to move around *strings*, then a regex based approach would put us in a fairly good position.

Comment: Why `replaceAll`, not `replaceFirst` ?

Comment: @khelwood In this particular case, since the pattern covers the entire string, I would expect `replaceFirst` and `replaceAll` to basically do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

try this code: If you wanna get what you want, it is 7th element

> ```
> String s= "alcaalde";
> char[] cs = s.toCharArray();
> cs[0] = cs[7];  
> s = new String(cs);
> ```